# How to use NOT in Where Clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

what is the difference between if i wrote the NOT query in the following ways.

```
SELECT iBatchID,COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE NOT iBatchID  IN (1) GROUP BY iBatchID

SELECT iBatchID,COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE iBatchID NOT IN (1) GROUP BY iBatchID
```

what is the difference in between if i am using `WHERE NOT iBatchID  IN (1)`  and `WHERE iBatchID NOT IN (1)` ?

Comment: Check the execution plan to see if there's a difference.

Comment: From my understanding it's not any different than saying `!(5 == 3)` and `5 != 3`. They both evaluate to the same thing. Except that the latter better conveys your purpose.

Comment: Depending on your indexes, I suppose the compiler could choose a different path, but I just ran tests against two simple tables and got the same execution plan for both methods.

Comment: @Michael i just check their Execution Plans both are same and having 50% of their Query Cost.

Comment: @izuriel when i was doing this for such a field i was having values in that Field "INF" where i am using <Column Name> NOT LIKE '%INF%' in my where condition it gives me error and when i do that by NOT <column  Name> LIKE '%INF%' it gives me returns without errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.  They will have the same query result.

And I believe the execution plans should be identical, but the best way to find that out is to capture the actual execution plans of each query.

I personally always choose `... WHERE SomeCol NOT IN (...)`, as it reads a little clearer than `... NOT WHERE SomeCol IN (...)`.  But this is all personal preference and what you feel to be more readable and maintainable.